# Regex with 3 characters long and at least one letter

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I wondering if it is possible to have this test in one regex 
Length at least 3 and at least one letter

I test regex like this

```
([a-zA-Z]{1,}).(\w{3,})
```

but not working

sample :

> Z56 => OK
>
> 1567 => KO
>
> EE => KO

thx you

> 78 I => OK

Comment: `^(?=.{3}).*[A-Za-z]`?

Comment: `^[A-Za-z].{2,}|^.+[A-Za-z].+|^.{2,}[A-Za-z]` would work too

Comment: `^(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{3,}$` If you want to capture the characters also.

Comment: Did any regex work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the characters then:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])\w{3,}$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/39kWEo/2/)

1. `^` Matches the start of the string.
2. `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` Is a *positive lookahead assertion* requiring that the input contains a letter.
3. `\w{3,}` Matches 3 or more word characters (so the input must be length 3 or longer).
4. `$` Matches the end of the string.

Use the following regex if the input can be 3 or more characters of any type as long as there is at least one letter (there is a discrepancy between the the question title, which just states 3 *characters* and the regex you attempted), so it is not entirely clear which one is intended:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{3,}$
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for as I understand is this one:

```
^(?:([a-zA-Z]{1})(\w{0,2})|((?:\s*\w){0,3}))$
```

I added `^` and `$` to specify that the string must start and end, and The second part `{0,2}` to set the length between 0 and 2, you can change the first part `{1}` with `?` to accept empty strings, and the alternative `|` to capture the last example `78 I`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z]).{3,}
```

Should work.